# External Script file (SAP CAI) Load Error

Tags: metadata, chatbot, sap-conversational-ai

We are seeing error in console when we try to call SAP CAI in local index.html page. This used to work earlier. If I try running index.html page standalone I can see bot loaded.

[image: lenter image description here]

But when I use Node.JS application and open same page (index.html) with below URL it is not loading.

[image]

Below is my Index.html page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look at the error message in the Chrome console you can actually see the root cause. Your Node Webserver is configured with a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), which is a security measure of browsers for example to avoid [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

In your example the CSP directive [script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) is set to "self". This information returned from the webserver tells the browser, from which origins it should allow to fetch and execute (java)script.

In a nutshell your browser is following the guidance configured in your webserver, to not trust script sources hosted elsewhere. To fix this you should look up the documentation of the webserver framework used in your example and allow the origin of the SAP Conversational AI script within your CSP settings.